# Dashboard is stuck

Tags: macbook-pro, error, dashboard

That's it. On my MacBook Pro the dashboard is stuck. I can't click the arrow in the bottom right corner, clicking more widgets doesn't do anything, clicking the safari icon on web clip opens safari but doesn't show it. Pressing he pause button does the same thing with iTunes. I can do command tab and see that, right now, google chrome, Safari, and iTunes are open right now (as well as finder, duh) but I can't actually switch to those. The force quit keyboard shortcut doesn't seem to do anything. Closing the cover and opening up a bit after doesn't do anything. I want a solution that doesn't require restarting the computer so that I don't have to wait for so long in the future. What can I do?

I can't tell anything about software, I think it's Yosemite or Mavericks but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you press cmd + option + esc - it should bring up a module similar to the task manager on Windows. From there, you can force quit any application you are in including finder.